# Batch Script not raising ERRORLEVEL on failure

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, cmd, scripting, errorlevel

I am learning Windows batch scripting. I need to raise errors when copy, move or delete operations fail. I have made a sample script and for some reason, when the operation fails I cannot get the ERRORLEVEL to rise. I run the script and the files either do not exist or are opened in another program and stderr messages are output to console, but ERRORLEVEL never rises, why is this? Also, is there any way to pipe stderr into a variable I could check, if I cannot get ERRORLEVEL to rise?

My code is as below:

```
`@Echo Off
ECHO.
Set /P myVar=Please enter a value:
Echo var = %myVar%
ECHO Trying to delete the file dummy.csv >> log.txt
Set myVar2 = nothing
DEL C:\dummy420.csv  
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO There was an error
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
REM 2>myVar2
REM Echo 2>
REM Echo %myVar2%
Echo 2>&1
REM && (echo yourCommand was successful) || (echo yourCommand failed)
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO There was an error
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
Move ""C:\dummy420.csv" D:\"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ECHO There was an error
Set /P dummy=Press Enter to End`
```

This is my output:

```
Please enter a value:hello
var = hello
C:\dummy420.csv
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
0
ECHO is off.
0
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Press Enter to End
```

Comment: Just to add something, the attempts at echoing ERRORLEVEL always return '0' and the IF statements never fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEL` command does not change the errorlevel - [more info](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6089)
Check the debenham suggestion to detect failed deletion:

```
3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 del C:\dummy420.csv|findstr . && echo DEL failed || echo DEL succeeded
```

to change errorlevel:

```
3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 del C:\dummy420.csv|findstr .&& cmd /c exit /b 1
```

Comment: Which commands produce error levels for which conditions? Is there any way I can capture stderr easily into a variable? I guess move and copy don't raise errorlevel either?

EDIT: Oh, I see you are capturing and examining stderr.....

Comment: @IbadRahman - copy and move will set errorlevel correctly .Problem is only with `RD`,`DEL` and redirection.The posted line will raise the errorlevel through `FINDSTR` command.

Comment: What are you doing here? as long as stderr is anything at all (not empty or null) you detect an error? What does the pipe before the findstr do? Anyway...I'll read your link...TY!