# How do I handle errors in running commands on a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I have this batch file which is supposed to find and delete specific files if found, but it keeps returning and displaying errors when the files are not found.
I had deleted the /S switch from the DELETE command to make the found files silent.
The code is below:

```
For /F "delims=" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S "*,*" ^| findstr ",[0-9][0-9]*$" '
) Do Del "%%A"
DEL /Q *.bak
ECHO bak files deleted
DEL /Q *.prjpcb.zip
ECHO Project History Zips deleted
DEL /Q *.pcbdoc.zip
ECHO PCB History Zips deleted
DEL /Q *.SchDoc.zip
ECHO Schematic History Zips deleted
DEL /Q *.PcbLib.zip
ECHO PCB Library History Zips deleted
DEL /Q *.SchLib.zip
ECHO Schematic Library History Zips deleted
DEL /Q *.OutJob.zip
ECHO Output Jobs History Zips deleted
ECHO on
TIMEOUT 5
```

How do I get the file to display only the echo when it deletes the files and nothing if nothing is found?

Comment: Type `del /?` into a command prompt window, so you'll find out that the `/S` option has nothing to do with a kind of silent mode. Anyway, you could use `if exist *.bak del /Q *.bak` to avoid error messages if the files do not exist, or you could also use `del /Q *.bak 2> nul` to suppress error messages...

Comment: What is really silly is the fact that the `del` command *clears* the `ErrorLevel` even in case of errors, so when files could not be found or not be accessed, for instance; perhaps you want to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33403497) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077745)...

Comment: I'd also offer the option to check existence before invoking a delete instruction, then check again before outputting a message. e.g. `If Exist "glob" (Del /A /F /Q "glob" 1>NUL & If Not Exist "glob" Echo All glob files deleted.)`.

Comment: OK. I have restored the /S switch. But I now get the files found and deleted or files not found! All I require is 'Files deleted' if found or nothing if nothing found.

Comment: How does the 'Exist "glob" ' work? Would I need to replace 'glob' with the names of the various files to find and delete? Do I need the speech quotes too?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to nul, if you really just never want to see any information from a command:

```
del /q *.bak >nul 2>&1
```

`>nul` redirects *standard* output, and `2>&1` redirects *error* output to the same place as *standard* output.  Note that `>nul` can be written as `1>nul` because it's the "first" output stream (standard).

Further note that `nul` represents a special case for the 2 output streams, such that you can do this:

```
del /q *.bak >nul 2>nul
```

https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html